# Python file.read() method

Tags: python

I'm reading a text file, line by line, using Python.  Each line is of a variable length.  The first line could be 10 characters, the next one could be 100; there's no way of telling.  Presently, I issue a file.readline() method for each line, process it, and then save it to a database.  This method guarantees me one full line of input.  I'd like to do this faster however.  Is there a way to do a bulk read using the Python file.read() method such that I can guarantee an end-of-line read character when the buffer stops in the middle of a line?  What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that `file.readline()` is an actual performance bottleneck? If not, stop trying to optimize it.

Comment: Do you think reading a file line by line is approximately as fast as reading the file into memory and parsing it that way?

Comment: Even if readline is significantly slower than read, (and remember if you read, you then have to split('\n')), if your program is spending 90% of it's time elsewhere, you're better off optimising elsewhere first.  Grab a profiler and see where your program really spends its time.

Comment: Everything @Perkins says is what's really important here… But yes, I think it is approximately as fast, or possibly even faster. `readline` is based on `read`, which is buffered. So it's reading things in optimal chunks, and scanning small buffers. If you have huge lines (much longer than the buffer size/disk block size), there may be some cost to the wasted scanning, but if you have typical lines, it'll probably be faster because of reducing paging (and, if your Python or libc is very smart, maybe even a bit of parallelism through async reads, although that's probably not happening).

Comment: Abarnert, how can I see what the buffer size / disk block is set to?  Can I adjust these settings?

Answer (score 6):

The typical way to handle these are just:

```
for line in fileobj:
    process(line)
```

There's no way to actually specify that `read` ends at the end of a line.  You could do something kludgy with `fileobj.seek`.  Basically, you'd read N bytes, find the last newline in the returned string (using `string.rfind`) you could seek backward that many bytes.

---

Of course, if you have sufficient memory, you can read the entire file in at once:

```
list_of_lines = fileobj.readlines()
```

---

However, I'm really not positive that you'll see any noticeable speedup here.  Are you sure you're not optimizing before you need to?

Comment: To be clear, `for line in fileobj:` will do buffering behind the scenes. Doing fancy things with read is very unlikely to beat the native buffering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ..

```
lines = file_handle.read().split('\n')
# Or 
lines = file_handle.readlines()
```

Check their documentation for accurate behavior with `'\n'`.

Comment: Why do this when you can iterate directly over the file?

Comment: I was hoping that a file.read(100 * 1024) would yield better results, but it would invariably end up in the middle of a line.  I'd then have to read one byte at a time until an end of line character was located.  I realize I could use a file.readlines() or a file.read() for the entire file, but for really big files, I wouldn't have enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

The way the encoders I've messed with have done this, is to read whatever's there, or a particular chunk size, note the position of the last newline (.rfind('\n')), process the data up to that newline, and then store from the newline to the end of the chunk in a list.  When reading the next block, you read from the same position as you stopped reading before, and you append the leftover string from before onto it.  The performance was reasonable, and it's stable, of course this was for network sockets, where you can't seek backwards, I'm not sure which method would actually perform better on files.